# Youtube controls missing

Tags: 14.04, firefox, youtube

I'm running 14.04

I've noticed recently the control buttons are missing from all Youtube videos I try to view. I can still click on and use the controls (play, full screen, etc.) but they are all invisible. Only the playback time is visible and the volume control shows on mouseover.

I've tried reinstalling the flashplugin-installer package to no effect. Right-clicking on the video gives me the html5 context menu so I suppose it's not a flash problem in the first place.

This problem is occurring in Firefox, from Chromium everything appears normally.

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 144c
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)

[image: youtube]

Comment: Try unchecking Enable hardware acceleration, under flash settings.  You can also try updating your video drivers.

Comment: I was gonna try changing the hardware acceleration setting but it's not a flash video. I'll look into upgrading the video driver, currently I have i915.

Comment: Have you tried different browsers; chromium, firefox, opera etc?

Comment: I should have already tried that, controls appear normally through Chromium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the issue is arising from the [User Agent Overrider addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-overrider/) (version 0.2.3). I am able to restore normal functionality simply by clicking its menu icon (a quick enable/disable toggle switch) and reloading the Youtube tab.

[image]